# Weird behavior with spark save parquet

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am experiencing a quite unexpected behavior when trying to write a pyspark dataframe as parquet after making multiple cleaning operations.
What I noticed is that when I have multiple stages sparks writes only few records. 
(the output file is only 5mb and about 21k rows whereas I expect about 110M rows and 32gb of data)

However, in another experiment When I just load the dataframe from csv and then write it without any cleaning (only 1 stage). It writes the full dataframe.

FYI: I am using databricks and writing on azure blob storage with the following code snippet.

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").option("header", "true").format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save('path')
```

[image]

The output files in the blob:
[image]

Any explanations or recommendations?

Comment: what is the actual number of record of the dataframe before write to parquet ? try a `df.count()`. Btw your parquet output is compressed, so the size should be way lower than csv.

Comment: Just before the write I have the 110M rows. I found out that it is a problem of columns schema when I parse all columns in String format, it writes all with no problem. But, if the columns have mixed types (IntegerType , DateType ...) I get this behavior

Comment: can you please check `df.count` before saving as parquet.

Comment: As I told previously, just before the write, the count operation give 110M rows.
The problem appears when I write parquet or csv and it disappears when I cast columns type to strings. I think it is due to the Null values in certain rows

Comment: I faced a similar issue. I was reading a csv with a column having some `NULL`s, and Spark could not read it as a numeric type (resulting in all values in the dataframe being nulls). Reading that column as `StringType` worked.